# Custom workflow in SharePoint online for document uploading

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am new to all of this. Recently i got a user story for document uploading in a library.
The story is " I want to upload a form and when i upload it in the library, the document should be in Draft state.
After that a mail should be sent to my manager and after the manager approves it, the document should be in Publish state."
Note: There can be numerous users uploading their documents in the library.
I believe it is kinda like a customization. I am not allowed to use Visual Studio or SharePoint designer. 
Is there any way i can complete this story?

Comment: You can use MS Visio using SharePoint Workflow template and then import it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MS Visio using SharePoint Workflow template and then import it.

More information and steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/workflow-development-in-sharepoint-designer-and-visio)

Comment: I am not sure if I can use Visio but I heard that Nintex can be used for the workflow as well. So should I approach Nintex ?

Comment: yes please go ahead as microsoft discontinued Microsoft SP Designer after SP 2013 release but visio is a good option as well